# Change a stored procedure from SELECT INTO to INSERT INTO using SQL Server 2016

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I'm having trouble finding the correct syntax.

I have

```
SELECT
    A.[Journal ISSN], A.[ISSN Primary], A.[ISSN Secondary], A.[Journal Title],
    pubYear  = B.[Key],
    ImpactFactor = B.[Value]
INTO 
    A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020_ROWS
FROM
    A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020 A  
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT * 
     FROM OPENJSON((SELECT A.* For JSON Path, Without_Array_Wrapper))                      
     WHERE [Key] NOT IN ('ID', 'ISSN Primary', 'ISSN Secondary', 'URL_Data', 'Journal ISSN', 'Journal Title', 'Other', 'Columns', 'ToExclude', 'Category')) B
```

And this works well when I drop the Table and and run the code. What I would like to do is to change it into an `INSERT` statement so it would start like

```
INSERT INTO A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020_ROWS 
      ([Journal ISSN], [ISSN Primary], [ISSN Secondary], [Journal Title], .....
```

IF need be I can create a temp table convert the columns into rows and THEN add them but if there is a syntax that would work and skip that step that would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax `INSERT SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020_ROWS
     ([Journal ISSN],[ISSN Primary],[ISSN Secondary],[Journal Title], ...)
Select A.[Journal ISSN],A.[ISSN Primary],    A.[ISSN Secondary], A.[Journal Title]
       ,pubYear  = B.[Key]  ,ImpactFactor = B.[Value]
From  A_ADMIN_IMPACT_FACTORS_2020 A
Cross Apply ( Select * 
      From  OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ))                
      Where [Key] not in ('ID','ISSN Primary','ISSN Secondary','URL_Data','Journal ISSN'
                          ,'Journal Title','Other','Columns','ToExclude', 'Category')
       ) B
```

Comment: Perfect-- Thank you